# Match list to dictionary with list values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to get keys by comparing a list to a dictionary with list as its values. Subjects is my list and School is my dictionary.

```
subjects = ['English','Mathematics']
Schools = {'School1': ['English','Mathematics','Humanities'],
'School2': ['English','Science','Programming'],
'School3': ['English','Art','Mathematics']}
```

Im having trouble retrieving the keys in this case. My expected output would be for School1 and School3 to be returned

Answer (score 1):

As i understood, you want to return lists which contains `subject` list's item. If so, you can implement it like this:

```
result=[]
for item in Schools:
    contains_all =  all(elem in Schools[item] for elem in subjects)
    if contains_all:
        result.append(Schools[item])
```

What i did is if item in `Schools` list contains subject, append it in `result` list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner for you.

```
x = [school_name 
         for school_name, school_content in Schools.items() 
         if all(
             subject in school_content 
                 for subject in subjects
         )
    ]
# ['School1', 'School3']
```